# How do I formulate this linear programing problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

A firm plans to purchase at least 200 quintals of scarp containing high-quality metal X and low-quality metal Y.Itdecides that the scrap to be purchased must contain at least 100 quintals of X-metal and not more than 35 quintals of Y – metal. The firm can purchase the scrap from two suppliers (A and B) in unlimited quantities. The percentage of X and Y metals in terms of weight in the scraps supplied by a and B is given below

```
Metals           Supplier A          Supplier B
   x                25%                75%
   Y                10%                20%
```

The price of A’s scrap is 200 per quintal and that of B’s $ 400 per quintal. Formulate this problem as an LP model to determine the quantities that the firm should bury from the two supplies so as to minimize total purchase cost.

I did this,

```
I took x1= quantity of metal x
       x2= quantity of metal y
 min z = 200x1+400x2
Subject to  x1+x2>200
```

Please help me with the table

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Or do you have a specific question? To show your attempt make an edit of your question.

Comment: @callculus, I updated the question

Comment: So far so good. The constraint for high quality metal is $0.25x_1+0.75x_2\geq 100$ The corresponding text is " *Itdecides that the scrap to be purchased must contain at least 100 quintals of X-metal* " It is comprehensible?

Comment: Yeah, it's. And  The constraint for low-quality metal is 0.1x1+0.2x2<=35 ? @callculus

Comment: Yes, that´s right. So at least the non-negativity constraint is missing.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks a lot. But I saw the same question on a webpage. It said, subject to, _*x1+x2<100*_, _*x1 +3x2 > 400*_ and _*x1 + 2x2 < 350*_

Comment: Subjet to what?

Comment: @callculus, sorry now I updated the comment

Comment: First of all I it s ivery good that you have defined the variables, really. But it is not  right. $x_1$: Amount of scrap from  supplier A.; $x_2$: Amount of scrap from  supplier B. The definition can be read off from the question. And also the constraints makes more sense now.

Comment: Oh yeah man, that's right.

Comment: It is all clear now?

Comment: @callculus, I get it now, but how do I justify _x1+3x2>400_ and _x1 + 2x2 < 350_

Comment: @callculus yes almost clear, this formulation is hard for me man

Comment: The first constraint is four times of $0.25x_1+0.75x_2\geq 100$ to get integers. They are equivalent.

Comment: Ah I see man, thanks a lot. You helped me a lot. Thank you for giving your valuable time for a slow turtle like me. Can I get an upvote ?

Comment: Learning and understanding takes time. So you have reached your goal. Congrats. You´re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments above I post the model in whole.

\begin{align*}
    &
\color{maroon}{\textrm{Variables}} \\  &x_1 : \  \textrm{Quantity of scrap which is bought from supplier A}. \\ &x_2 : \  \textrm{Quantity of scrap which is bought from supplier B}. \\ & \\ &\color{maroon}{\textrm{Objective function}}  \\ &\textrm{min} \ \ 200x_1+400x_2  \\ &  \\ &\color{maroon}{\textrm{Constraints}}  \\& x_1+x_2\geq 200  \\ &0.25x_1+0.75x_2\geq 100  \qquad \ \textrm{ (High-quality metal X)}  \\ &0.10x_1+0.20x_2\leq \ \ 35  \qquad \ \textrm{ (Low-quality metal Y)}  \\ & \\&\color{maroon}{\textrm{
Non-negativity condition}} \\&x_1,x_2\geq 0
\end{align*}

Comment: I didn't have enough rep to upvote back then. Now I have some. Thank you so much for all your efforts. God bless you good man

Comment: @DarkDevil Thanks for you vote and your comment.